# Unit testing, OxyPlot data point comparation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, oxyplot

I want to compare a data point received from a postgres database with the data pointer that i have send to the database.

```
[TestMethod]
        public void MeasurementWriteReadDelete()
        {
            Measurement core = new Measurement();

            DbRepository database = null;


            database = DbRepository.GetInstance();
            database.EstablishConnection("postgres", "1234");
            Assert.IsTrue(database.IsConnected);

            core.Title = "aaa";
            core.Description = "bbb";
            core.Tester = "1.22";
            core.ForceTravelCharacteristic.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 2));
            core.PullForceCharacteristic.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 4));
            core.ReturnSpeedCharacteristic.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 1));
            core.EngagementPoint.X = 10;
            core.EngagementPoint.Y = 13;
            core.CreateInDatabase(DbRepository.GetInstance());
            core.Id = Convert.ToUInt32(core.CurrentID);

            core.ReadCharacteristicFromDatabase(DbRepository.GetInstance());

            core.ReadMetadataFromDatabase(DbRepository.GetInstance());



            Assert.AreEqual("aaa", core.Title);
            Assert.AreEqual("bbb", core.Description);
            Assert.AreEqual("1.22", core.Tester);
            Assert.AreEqual(10, core.EngagementPoint.X);
            Assert.AreEqual(13, core.EngagementPoint.Y);


            Assert.AreEqual(  , core.ForceTravelCharacteristic);

            core.DeleteFromDatabase(DbRepository.GetInstance());
```

I want to compare this:

```
core.ForceTravelCharacteristic.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 2));
```

with the data from database:

```
core.ForceTravelCharacteristic
```

How can i do this comparison?

Comment: Im trying to better underestand...what is the type of your ForceTravelCharasteristic object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void MeasurementWriteReadDelete()
        {
            Measurement core = new Measurement();

            DbRepository database = null;



            ForceTravelCharacteristicVal = new LineSeries();
            ForceTravelCharacteristicVal.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 3));


            database = DbRepository.GetInstance();
            database.EstablishConnection("postgres", "1234");
            Assert.IsTrue(database.IsConnected);

            core.Title = "aaa";
            core.Description = "bbb";
            core.Tester = "1.22";
            core.ForceTravelCharacteristic.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 3));
            core.ForceTravelCharacteristic.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 5));
            core.ForceTravelCharacteristic.Points.Add(new DataPoint(100, -100));
            core.PullForceCharacteristic.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 4));
            core.ReturnSpeedCharacteristic.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 1));
            core.EngagementPoint.X = 10;
            core.EngagementPoint.Y = 13;

            core.CreateInDatabase(DbRepository.GetInstance());

            core.Id = Convert.ToInt32(core.CurrentID);
            core.ReadCharacteristicFromDatabase(DbRepository.GetInstance());
            core.ReadMetadataFromDatabase(DbRepository.GetInstance());

            Assert.AreEqual("aaa", core.Title);
            Assert.AreEqual("bbb", core.Description);
            Assert.AreEqual("1.22", core.Tester);
            Assert.AreEqual(10, core.EngagementPoint.X);
            Assert.AreEqual(13, core.EngagementPoint.Y);
            Assert.AreEqual(ForceTravelCharacteristicVal.Points.ElementAt(0).X, core.ForceTravelCharacteristic.Points.ElementAt(0).X);
            Assert.AreEqual(ForceTravelCharacteristicVal.Points.ElementAt(0).Y, core.ForceTravelCharacteristic.Points.ElementAt(0).Y);


            core.DeleteFromDatabase(DbRepository.GetInstance());
        }

        public LineSeries ForceTravelCharacteristicVal { get; set; }

    }
```